# Django Rest Framework Oauth2 token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0

I was following this tutorial https://yeti.co/blog/oauth2-with-django-rest-framework/ but then I hit a bump. I could register a new user but when I tried to get a token using the format:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" http://<client_id>:<client_secret>@localhost:8000/o/token/
```

I would get an error saying there is a `credential` error. However, if I created a new user using `the admin page`, I would be able to get the token. My guess is that in the `sign_up` view, the password is not `hashed` and so there is some error but I do not know how to change it.

serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrCreate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.serializers import SignUpSerializer

class SignUp(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SignUpSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrCreate,)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? (From the original documentation) `curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/`

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed curl does not work because the format is invalid. By typing `http://<client_id>:<client_secret>@localhost` you are misunderstanding the concept of oAuth2, and thinking that somehow `<client_id>:<client_secret>` is a valid user in your `localhost` machine. However, the client id and secret refer to a registered client-side application.

Use this format instead:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```